# Online entropy evaluation algorithm

Tags: solr, lucene, statistics, real-time, entropy

Is there a way to evaluate [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29) on a stream of discrete values similar to [SumamryStatistics](http://commons.apache.org/math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/stat/descriptive/SummaryStatistics.html) for mean and deviation?
I need this algorithm for real-time solr component, and it will probably iterate over large document collections(100,000).

Related question, what is the best way to compute Entropy in Map Reduce like environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a way - it depends somewhat on the characteristics of the stream, and what you want to do with the results.

The sample entropy is a function of the sample *probability distribution*. You can store a running count of each value together with the running total count, which means that the distribution can be calculated on demand. Excuse my sloppy Java, it's been about a year since I wrote it.

```
Map<K,Integer> runningCount = new Map<K,Integer>();
int totalCount = 0;

public void addValue(K k) {
    runningCount.insert(k, runningCount.get(k) + 1);
    totalCount += 1;
}

public Map<K,Double> getDistribution() {
    Map<K,Double> dist = new Map<K,Double>();
    for (K k : runningCount.keys()) {
        dist.insert(k, runningCount.get(k) / totalCount);
    }
    return dist;
}
```

This means that you can also compute the entropy on demand:

```
public double getEntropy() {
    Map<K,Double> dist = getDistribution();
    double entropy = 0;
    for (K k : dist.keys()) {
        double p = dist.get(k);
        entropy -= p * Math.log(p);
    }
    return entropy;
}
```

This algorithm is O(*n*) to compute both the distribution and the entropy, where *n* is the number of values your stream might take on. It is independent of the number of values in the stream, as you can see from the fact that the `addValue` method doesn't store the stream values.

Comment: Yes, you are right, solution is quite simple, we probably can switch map to array to increase performance. This will not work for continuous variable, but I do not need this. Thanks.